# What is the winrar command line archive file

Tags: command-line, archive, winrar

How can I create a file using the command line Winrar my archive

I've used this command but it did not work

`WinRAR.exe a -afzip -df e:\test.rar e:\test.csv`

It gives me the error:

`Error: 'WinRAR' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to make sure that you let the command line interpreter know where winrar.exe is. This can be done in either of (at least) three ways. The following examples assume that winrar was installed into  `c:\Program Files\WinRAR`.

**Specify the full path to winrar.exe on the commandline:**

```
"c:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -afzip -df e:\test.zip e:\test.csv
```

*or*

**Navigate to the folder where winrar is installed**

```
c:
cd "\Program Files\WinRAR"
WinRAR.exe a -afzip -df e:\test.zip e:\test.csv
```

*or*

**Add the path that contains winrar to the `PATH` environment variable**

This is described in some detail [here](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them).

Other than that your command line works just fine, but you should name your output file `test.zip` since you are using the 'zip' format for compression and not 'rar', otherwise there may be problems opening the resulting files in for example WinRAR.

Comment: WinRAR a -afzip -df g:\test.zip g:\test.csv

Error:

'WinRAR' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Updated the answer with more info, and also added the error message to the question.

Comment: Thank you, problem solved.

But one thing to say here. When the installation WinRAR give notice that the application

There are no spaces between words, for example:

E: \ Program Files \ WinRAR

'Program Files' As you can see, there is space between the two words is not correct

The correct method:

  E: \ ProgramFiles \ WinRAR

I mean, they were sensitive to space in the command prompt.